# Length-wise crack in acoustic guitar neck - cause for concern and possible fixes?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, lutherie, guitar-neck

I've "inherited" an acoustic guitar between 10 and 15 years of age. It is in very good condition except for a small crack in the neck (see picture). The crack looks like it hasn't occurred recently since some dust has accumulated in it. Generally, the neck still seems stable, there is no concerning motion or noise even when I pull on the headstock.

Is this cause for worry? I assume this might have been causes either by a too dry climate or the truss rod (although the neck seems to be well adjusted, the action is not too high and there is no fret buzz). This was originally a rather expensive Furch so I don't think this is due to poor material or craftsmanship.

Can I "fix" this with glue even though clamping is probably not possible in this case? Or at the very least, can I fix this cosmetically with some filler material?

[image: crack in neck]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd be inclined to leave it as it is. Especially if the tuning is stable. Keep an eye on it - measure it every 3 months or so. Just maybe, I'd take it to a luthier for a check, but not worry about it. Were it perpendicular to where it is, yes, I'd be quite concerned, but, for now, let sleeping dogs lie, so they say.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Do Luthiers usually charge for checks like this even if nothing needs to be repaired?